# what is the correct config for ubuntu apache2 virtualhost on port different from 80

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, subdomain

i've just inherited a server ubuntu 10.04 running already tomcat on port 80.so apache 2 `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` has Listen 8858.

i pointed my subdomain let's say admin.domain.com to the ip of that box so `xx.xx.xx.xx:8858` and `admin.domain.com:8858` both sends me to the root file "it works"

so i did create under `/var/www/vhots/admin.domain.com/htdocs` and `/var/www/vhots/admin.domain.com/log`  my first config looks is below and that basically  after reloading and restarting the apache2
gives me this error

> VirtualHost *:8858 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
>   httpd (pid 7466?) not running

```
###/etc/apache2/apache2.cong
NameVirtualHost *
#NameVirtualHost *:8858
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
</Virtualhost>


###/etc/apache2/sites-available/admin.domain.com
<VirtualHost *:8858>
    ServerAdmin sensei@domain.com
    ServerName admin.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.admin.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhots/admin.domain.com/htdocs
            <Directory /var/www/vhosts/admin.domain.com/htdocs>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/admin.domain.com/log/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/admin.domain.com/log/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
  </VirtualHost>
```

So after reading [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#port) i've uncommented NameVirtualHost *:8858 that i initially put there making me have both NameVirtualHost * and NameVirtualHost *:8858 now i have a warn message but then the server refuse to start

> NameVirtualHost *:8858 has no VirtualHosts
>   httpd (pid 27536?) not running
>   [warn] NameVirtualHost *:8858 has no VirtualHosts                                                                                                                   [fail]

How can i get it up? Thanks for reading this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

- [Setting Up Name Based Virtual Hosting on Ubuntu Server | Ubuntu Tutorials](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/09/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting)
- http://www.debuntu.org/2006/02/22/7-virtual-hosting-using-apache-2/

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a Tomcat running on port 80, you can't attach Apache to same port. HTTP URL without a port, like http://admin.domain.com, assumes the port is 80.

So, in order to make your site accessible without a port (:8858) you'd need to move Tomcat to another port.

There's another solution if you have 2 IP addresses on the same server, for example x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2. Then point Tomcat to first address and Apache to second with:

```
# Apache configuration
NameVirtualHost x.x.x.2:80

<VirtualHost x.x.x.2:80>
 #Your site configuration
</virtualHost>
```

In that case don't forget to repoint your DNS entries to correctly.

Comment: thanks for clarifying things up. No i don't have a second ip.So i will do with 8858.Now any clue on how to get the virtualhost up?

Comment: Just remove VirtualHost * configuration and NameVirtualHost *. Uncomment NameVirtualHost *:8858 and that should be it.